# If $ I = \int{( x^{10} + \sqrt{1+x^{20}})^{\frac{21}{10}}} dx $ then find $ I $ .

Tags: calculus, integration

As given in question,

$$ I = \int{( x^{10} + \sqrt{1+x^{20}})^{\frac{21}{10}}} dx $$

Then, $ I = ? $

I've tried:

• Taking $ x^{10} + \sqrt{1+x^{20}} $ as $ u $ and finding $ du/dx $ but that not helps anyway.

I didn't find any approach to go. I already have the knowledge of all basic integration formulae and substitution method.

An answer with strategy to solve these kind of problems will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not helpful here, but this kind of integrals are usually hard to be calculated by routine methods……

Comment: @xbh hmm........

Comment: See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x%5E10%2Bsqrt(1%2Bx%5E2))%5E2.1).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I also know how to use wolfarmalpha. It says no result. Please try to help here.

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: I rewrote the integrand as $\exp( 21/10 \arcsinh (x^{10}))$ and Maple was able to spit out a closed-form answer.  Not pretty, but actually, not that bad.

Comment: Mathematica  was able to spit out a closed-form answer only 38 pages with no using `FullSimplify` function.

Comment: There's a clever way to simplify $I'$. Can you figure it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, let $x=1/u$ gives
$$I  = - \int {{{\left( {\frac{1}{{{u^{10}}}} + \sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{{{u^{20}}}}} } \right)}^{21/10}}\frac{1}{{{u^2}}}du} = - \int {\frac{{{{\left( {1 + \sqrt {1 + {u^{20}}} } \right)}^{21/10}}}}{{{u^{23}}}}du} $$
then $u=v^{1/20}$:
$$I = - \frac{1}{{20}}\int {\frac{{{{\left( {1 + \sqrt {1 + v} } \right)}^{21/10}}}}{{{v^{23/20}}{v^{19/20}}}}dv} = - \frac{1}{{20}}\int {{{\left( {\frac{{1 + \sqrt {1 + v} }}{v}} \right)}^{21/10}}dv} $$
after that, $t = 1 + \sqrt {1 + v}$:
$$I = - \frac{1}{{20}}\int {{{\left( {\frac{t}{{{t^2} - 2t}}} \right)}^{21/10}}(2t - 2)dt} = - \frac{1}{{10}}\int {\frac{{t - 1}}{{{{(t - 2)}^{21/10}}}}dt} $$
finally $w=t-2$ will make the rest obvious. You will recover the answer given by the other user.

Comment: Do you think the $ u^{23} $ is correct instead of $ u^{63} $

Comment: @RaviPrakash I think $u^{23}$ is correct, why $63$?

Comment: Can you expand step 1 → step 2

Comment: Also, can you fully explain your idea of taking 1/u = x